# Linear Algebra of Symmetric Sums: a converse question

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

An on-going effort to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23247/fourier-series-representations-of-symmetric-and-non-symmetric-polygons) has brought up various [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/linear-algebra-of-symmetric-sums) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23762/a-symmetric-sum-question-that-may-use-complex-analysis). Most recently, I have been wondering: given a set of $n$ distinct non-zero complex numbers, $z_1, \dots, z_j, \dots , z_n$, and given the values of the first $n+1$ the power sums, $\mathcal{Z}_0, \mathcal{Z}_1, \dots, \mathcal{Z}_n$: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  z_{1}  & z_{2} & \cdots & z_{n} \\
  z_{1}^{2} & z_{2}^2 &  \cdots & z_{n}^{2} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  z_{1}^n  & z_{2}^n &  \cdots & z_{n}^n
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  1 \\
  \vdots  \\
  1
 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathcal{Z}_0  \\
  \mathcal{Z}_1 \\
  \mathcal{Z}_2  \\
  \vdots  \\
  \mathcal{Z}_n
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

from the *[Linear Algebra of Symmetric Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/linear-algebra-of-symmetric-sums)* question, we know that these $n$ equations (if you don't include $\mathcal{Z}_0 = n$) determine the $z_j$'s. What if we consider the converse? How does requiring the $z_j$'s to be non-zero and distinct restrict the possible values for the power sums, the $\mathcal{Z}_k$'s? Clearly, they cannot all be zero, but there must be a large number of other choices for $\mathcal{Z}_1, \dots, \mathcal{Z}_n$ that produce non-distinct or zero values for some of the $z_j$'s.

---

***Note***

This may appear to ask two different questions:

1. What is the effect of requiring the
   $z_j$'s to be non-zero?
2. What is the
   effect of requiring them to be
   distinct?

But a $z_j$ that is zero or two, say $z_j$ and $z_l$, that are the same have a very similar effect on the power sum equations: they shrink the problem from a problem with $n$ independent equations to one with $n-1$ (or fewer) independent equations and an extra dependent equation or two.

In fact, considering this question in this fashion, I may have a sort of answer, albeit a horrendously ugly answer. Consider each of the myriad, but finite number of, ways the $z_j$'s can be degenerate: one $z_j$ zero, two of them zero, one zero and two not distinct, etc., and with that as an assumption, using the technique of the second half of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23762/a-symmetric-sum-question-that-may-use-complex-analysis/24930#24930), attempt to calculate the dependent $\mathcal{Z}_k$ equations from the others. If it works, the present set of $\mathcal{Z}_k$'s is degenerate.

Anyway, I am looking for a more tractable answer which might allow me to look at some sets of values for the $\mathcal{Z}_k$'s (especially sets with lots of zeros) and recognize them as not possible.

---

***A Reformulation of the Question***

Given the discussion in the note, or given Arturo's determinant calculation in his comment, we can reformulate the question equivalently as:

Given a set of *any* $n$ complex numbers, $z_1, \dots , z_n$, and given the values of the first $n+1$ the power sums, $\mathcal{Z}_0, \mathcal{Z}_1, \dots, \mathcal{Z}_n$:

$$ \mathcal{Z}_0 =n $$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  z_{1}  & z_{2} & \cdots & z_{n} \\
  z_{1}^{2} & z_{2}^2 &  \cdots & z_{n}^{2} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  z_{1}^n  & z_{2}^n &  \cdots & z_{n}^n
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  \vdots  \\
  1
 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathcal{Z}_1 \\
  \mathcal{Z}_2  \\
  \vdots  \\
  \mathcal{Z}_n
 \end{bmatrix}
,$$
can you use the values of the power sums to determine whether the matrix is singular or not?

Comment: Dropping the first row, then, you get a Vandermonde matrix multiplies by $z_1\cdots z_n$. The determinant will then be equal to$$z_1\cdots z_n\prod_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n}(z_j-z_i).$$If the $z_i$ are nonzero and pairwise distinct, then the remaining matrix has nonzero determinant, so the system $M\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ always has a unique solution. So choosing either the $\mathcal{Z}_i$ or the vector $\mathbf{x}$ completely determines everything.  If either not all $z_i$ are nonzero, or $z_i=z_j$ for $i\neq j$, the system may or may not have a solution, and solutions may not be unique.

Comment: My question is: given only the $\mathcal{Z_k}$'s and that $x=(1,1, \dots, 1)$ can I tell if the matrix $M$ is singular or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you say that you want to know whether from knowing the values of the power sum symmetric polynomials on $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ you can determine whether the $z_i$ are pairwise distinct and nonzero, or not.

The power sum symmetric polynomials
\begin{align*}
p_1(z_1,\ldots,z_n) &= z_1+\cdots + z_n\\
p_2(z_1,\ldots,z_n) &= z_1^2 + \cdots + z_n^2\\
&\vdots\\
p_n(z_1,\ldots,z_n) &= z_1^n + \cdots + z_n^n
\end{align*}
generate the ring of symmetric polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$.

In particular, you can express the elementary symmetric polynomials in $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ as sums of rational multiples of products of the power sum symmtric polynomials. So you can express
\begin{align*}
e_1(z_1,\ldots,z_n) &= z_1+\cdots + z_n\\
e_2(z_1,\ldots,z_n) &= z_1z_2 + z_1z_3+\cdots+z_1z_n+z_2z_3+\cdots+z_{n-1}z_n\\
&\vdots\\
e_n(z_1,\ldots,z_n) &= z_1\cdots z_n
\end{align*}
in terms of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$.

Plugging in the values $\mathcal{Z}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{Z}_n$ that you know for $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, that would determine the values of $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. With the values of $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, you get the coefficients of
$$(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\cdots(x-z_n)$$
because the coefficients are precisely the elementary symmetric polynomials in $z_1,\ldots,z_n$.

But it is a trivial matter to determine if this polynomial has zero as a root, or if it has repeated roots (for the latter, check the gcd with the derivative). Thus, from the values of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ you can determine if the $z_i$ are pairwise distinct and nonzero, or not, which in turn tells you if $M$ is nonsingular or not.

In summary: yes, you can tell if $M$ is singular or nonsingular, by computing the polynomial $(x-z_1)\cdots(x-z_n)$ via symmetric polynomials.

How does this relate to the question in the first paragraph, though?

First: if you write the symmetric polynomial $z_1\cdots z_n$ in terms of the power symmetric polynomials, then setting this equal to $0$ gives you a polynomial with rational coefficients in $\mathcal{Z}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{Z}_n$. The $z_i$ are nonzero if and only if the $\mathcal{Z}_i$ do *not* satisfy this polynomial. This gives you precisely the locus of vectors $(\mathcal{Z}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{Z}_n)^T$ that are excluded by the condition "all $z_i$ are nonzero."

For example: take the case $n=2$. Then we express $z_1z_2$ in terms of $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1^2 + z_2^2$:
$$ z_1z_2 = \frac{1}{2}\left( (z_1+z_2)^2 - (z_1^2+z_2^2)\right) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{Z}_1^2 - \mathcal{Z}_2).$$
Therefore, one of $z_1$ and $z_2$ is zero if and only if $\mathcal{Z}_1^2 - \mathcal{Z}_2 = 0$.

Therefore, the vectors $(\mathcal{Z}_1,\mathcal{Z}_2)$ that are excluded by the condition "$z_1$ and $z_2$ are both nozero" are exactly the points that lie on the grap of $y=x^2$.

This is fairly straightforward to do in any value of $n$, once you express $z_1\cdots z_n$ in terms of the power sum symmetric polynomials. So certainly, it is easy to write down a polynomial expression that determines exactly the locus of all "bad $(\mathcal{Z}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{Z}_n)$" that lead to at least one $z_i$ equal to $0$.

**Added, Edited.** (*This is what I get for posting at 1am. I forget things like "discriminant" and "resultant."*)

To determine if the polynomial has repeated roots, you can just look at the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant). The discriminant is a function of the coefficients of $(x-z_1)\cdots(x-z)n)$, and since we can compute the coefficients using the $\mathcal{Z}_i$, then we can compute the discriminant. It will be  a polynomial in the coefficient, hence a polynomial in the $\mathcal{Z}_i$.

The key is that the discriminant is also equal to the product $\displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n}(z_i - z_j)^2$, and therefore the discriminant is equal to $0$ if and only if the polynomial has repeated roots. (In the $n=2$ case, what I was looking at, $\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{Z}_1^2 =\mathcal{Z}_2$, was just the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial, but with my algebra error and the hour, I failed to notice).

So: setting the discriminant equal to $0$ gives you the condition for repeated roots, and setting the constant term equal to $0$ gives you the condition for a root to be zero. The two together determine two varieties in affine $n$-space, and the locus of "bad tuples" is precisely their union.

In short: yes, you can determine exactly which $(\mathcal{Z}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{Z}_n)$ correspond to singular matrices and which to nonsingular matrices; it is described as the union of two affine varieties in $\mathbb{C}^n$, which can be written as two polynomials (with rational coefficients) in the $\mathcal{Z}_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that you have resolved the "some of $z_j$'s are zero" issue. There is an algebra error in your $n=2$ non-distinct discussion. The criteria should be $$\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{Z_1}^2=\mathcal{Z_2}.$$

Comment: @Eric: I think you're right. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: You know what? On reflection it's not that bad. You can just use the discriminant of the polynomial. I'll write this up later, and I think it will be pretty easy.

Comment: I found a straightforward way to calculate the constant term from the from the powers sums, but I have not found a good way to calculate the discriminant from the power sums. Is the only way to calculate the *all* the coefficients of the polynomial and then find the determinant of the Sylvester matrix?

Comment: @Eric: Honestly, I don't know. It's not something I've ever looked into.